# Active Directory : how to find the location of a user with the same title and copy it?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-4.0

I am trying to move a newly created user into the same folder as a user with the same title.

So for example, if user Becca has the title "Technical Support Officer" and newly created Barney has the title "Technical Support Officer", I want to be able to move Barney into the same folder as Becca.

I am fairly new to PowerShell and Active Directory module so I definitely appreciate any useful tips or commands.

```
$folderloca = Get-ADGroup -filter * | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*TiTle*"} | select name
```

I was aiming for something along the lines of the code above but wasn't quite certain where to go from here.

How do I find a user based off of title as well as find their location?

Comment: What do you mean by _folder_ ? An AD Group ? An Organizational Unit ? I would definitely recommend you to approach a colleague with some Active Directory knowledge and ask for some guidance.

Comment: Hey, sorry about the vagaries of my question! I would like to search the domain for multiple people of the same title and then locate which Organizational Unit they are in. It was end of the day yesterday and I was apparently very brain dead! I was able to take one look at my problem and figure it out today. Thank you for responding even though it was definitely a bad question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to search the domain for multiple people of the same
> title and then locate which Organizational Unit they are in.

You can use the below Command to solve the issue:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * |Where-Object{$_.Title -eq "testengineer"}| Select-Object Name,Title,DistinguishedName
```

[image]